# Asking for user to input screen size for a turtle project

Tags: python, input, window

I am brand new to Python and know very little. I am working on a project using turtles, where I need to ask the user to input the window width and height, but I am completely lost. I have come up with this so far.

```
w = int(input(w))
h = int(input(h))
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(w, h, 0, 0)
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you were almost there!

```
import turtle

w = int(input("Enter Width: "))
h = int(input("Enter Height: "))
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(w, h, 0, 0)
```

It looks like you forgot to import the turtle library, in addition notice the input lines. If you only want the prompt to be w or h it would need to be enclosed with " "

Comment: Oooohh I see! Thank you so much!!